# Displaying data with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I display tree data in my app. I have typical JSON structure to work with D3.

```
{
  name: 'test',
  children: [
    name: 'test2',
    children: []
  ]
  ...
}
```

I calculate nodes and render tree like on this tutorial http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092. My questions: Is it possible to display child node of root on different level? For example:

I have this:

[image]

I would like to have this:

[image]

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to use is the [Cluster Layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Cluster-Layout) which will put all leaf nodes at the same level.

Here is an example:

```
var data = {
    'name': 'root',
        'children': [{
        'name': 'level 1.a',
            'children': [{
            'name': 'level 2.a',
                'children': [{
                'name': 'level 3.a',
                'size': 3938
            }, {
                'name': 'level 3.b',
                'size': 3812
            }, {
                'name': 'level 3.c',
                'size': 743
            }]
        }, {
            'name': 'level 2.b',
                'children': [{
                'name': 'level 3.a',
                'size': 3534
            }, {
                'name': 'level 3.b',
                'size': 5731
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'level 1.b',
        children: []
    }]
};

var height = 300;
var width = 500;

var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
    .size([height, width - 100]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
});

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('width', width)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(40, 20)');

var nodes = cluster.nodes(data);
var links = cluster.links(nodes);

var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
    .data(links)
    .enter().append('path')
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .attr('d', diagonal);

var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('transform', function (d) {
    return 'translate(' + d.y + ',' + d.x + ')';
});

node.append('circle')
    .attr('r', 4.5);

node.append('text')
    .attr('dx', 8)
    .attr('dy', 3)
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.name;
});
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/w7xbcun3/)